# Since natural units can be discarded, does that mean that natural units are not required?

Tags: metaphysics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units says that in natural units, units can be discarded. This means that constants can be omitted. Does this imply that it is possible for quantities to still exist with no man-made units/equations?

Comment: It also says right after that that "it precludes the interpretation of an expression in terms of fundamental physical constants, such as e and c, unless it is known which units (in dimensionful units) the expression is supposed to have. In this case, the reinsertion of the correct powers of e, c, etc., can be uniquely determined." So if we want to be able to tell the difference between 1 for electric charge from 1 for speed, which we would if we want to connect the theory to the real world, units are still required. It is just that in the natural system they can be inferred from context.

Comment: Required by whom, how, for what???

Comment: Isn't this more of a [physics.se] question?

Answer (score 1):

"Natural units" are sometimes used in writing down physics equations because depending on the content of the equation, doing this can make the solution of the equation more straightforward and at times a little more obvious.

But to tie the solution back to the real world (where, for example, the speed of light is not ordinarily set equal to one), the appropriate unit conversions must still be made.

Answer (score 1):

All this is saying is that the *mathematics* of physics works without reference to the actual values of physical constants. Physical constants are scaling or scoping factors; they connect the (abstract) math to (concrete) physical behaviors so that the math can be used effectively in the real world. But we could substitute almost any arbitrary number for a known constant (excluding zero in some cases) and the math would still work perfectly well. The results would merely be scaled or shifted by a calculable amount.

Sometimes it's convenient to do this when we are more concerned about the magnitude or tendency of a effect than about the full measure of the effect. It makes life simpler for those who see what we're doing, but more confusing for those who don't, which is sometimes an acceptable tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you move fast and slow and ask someone to tell the difference, they usually can. It does not matter if they are physics teachers or math teacher, or if they use the Si or American units. Thus, there must be a common knowledge of quantity (speed is from 2 units) and that quantity does not need to be known or calculated.

Comment: There is no need to post an answer. I resolved it on my own-it works for my purposes.